# Unterminated string constant

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

My Description contains an apstrophe('). How to escape it.

```
<a href='javascript:select("<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(0), "'", "'") %>",
"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "'") %>");' title="<%=selRpt%>">
<span class='img-view'></span></a>
```

`"<%= pageBean.replace(list.getColumn(1), "'", "'") %>"` is the description part in my JSP Scriptlet which contains apstrophe(')

**My HTML View**

```
    <a href='javascript:select("JWCCA5",
"Worker's Compensation Form -  California Form 5020(New)");' 
title="Select Report"><span class='img-view'></span></a>
```